# Display a text field with single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an application that requires a text field to fade in with the value being loaded by AJAX. (I'm doing this all with jQuery), here's the code:

```
$("div#p"+eId+"_content").html("<input class='editPost' type='text' value='"
                               + oldCont
                               + "' id='p"
                               + eId 
                               + "_editBox' />");
```

Unfortunatly, `oldCont` can contain single quotes, which means the textbox will only contain `oldPost` up until that single quote. How could I display `oldCont` without having that problem, but still retaining that single quote (without the \ from escaping it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("div#p"+eId+"_content")
  .append( $("<input type='text' id='p"+eId+"_editBox' />")
           .addClass('editPost').val(oldCont));
```

...I think those parens line up .....  :-)

basically, use the val function on a jquery object and it'll take care of the escaping for you.  Similarly you can use the addClass, attr, etc. functions for other pieces of your html objects

Comment: That did it except I needed to remove one of the parenthesis at then end.